# Inject Interface with Generics in Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use Hilt to inject a generic interface implementation but it keeps giving me errors.

My interface looks like this:

```
interface Validator<in T> {
  fun validate(value: T): Boolean
}
```

And a typical implementation of it can be like this:

```
class FullNameValidator @Inject constructor() : Validator<String>{

   override fun validate(value: String): Boolean {
      val isValid = //Validation logic

      return isValid
    }
}
```

Now the way I am trying to use Hilt, i've tried to use @Bind method in a @Module like this

```
@Binds
abstract fun bindFullNameValidator(validator: FullNameValidator) : Validator<String>
```

Like I am doing with all interfaces implementations and it's working just fine.
But here, Hilt claims that it cannot find a way to inject the String object which is the generic type.

Is there a proper way to inject such `interface<T>` ?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: It's been a long time since and I am not working on this project anymore.. But I think i've just removed the <in > keyword  and then it worked for me..